# Late 80s - mid 90s Disney TV movie with mechs

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to identify a Disney TV movie from the late-80s to mid-90s.  The plot points that I can remember are:

- 3 teenagers on a spacecraft, all in recently in trouble at their (military?) academy so being sent somewhere
- the ship malfunctions
- no adults around, period
- they meet some alien woman who agrees to help them because she "thought they were much older warriors" rather than kids
- the kids somehow have mechs (they look **exactly** like the Battlech Timber Wolf/Mad Cat mech)
- harvesting ice on a planet for water, they encounter some gigantic worm creature that can sense heat

Comment: Live action\animation?

Comment: It was live action.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe i found what you're searching for, [*Hypernauts*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypernauts).

> The premise of the series was that three cadets from the Academy of Galactic Exploration become lost in a Hyper Bubble (hyperspace) mid-jump and must band together with an alien named Kulai in order to survive in an unfamiliar part of the galaxy. Kulai (unbeknownst to the cadets) is a Chalim priestess from a planet called Pyria, a planet that was strip-mined by a warlike race called the Triiad, led by the Pyran traitor, Paiyin. The sole purpose of the Triiad is to wipe out intelligent races, and in the process acquire raw materials from their destroyed planets to continually create new war machines using automated self-replicating factory ships called "Makers."

The giant heat-seeking worm is in the third episode, "Icebound".

> The Star Ranger begins to run low on water, so the Hypernauts land on a nearby ice moon where they discover an ancient space craft, and giant heat seeking worms.