# A show from the 90s about 3 teenagers and their robots

Tags: story-identification, mecha

It was a show about 3 teenagers I think, a white guy, black guy and an Asian girl that got stuck on a ship with their 3 robots. From what I recall their ship warped/jumped/hyperspaced in the wrong direction or it got messed up and they happened upon an alien fleet heading to earth. They all argued and bickered at first but went on to work together, the colors of their suits matched their mechs, I believe the colors were yellow, red and green i think? I can't remember much else about it. Anyone remember this?

Comment: Please add language, country of origin if you remember. That might help people to figure out.

Comment: Was this animated or live action?

Comment: See more comprehensive answer at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2805/late-80s-mid-90s-disney-tv-movie-with-mechs

Answer (score 2):

This *may* be Hypernauts, a show that briefly ran on YTV- although the bad-guy alien fleet (called the Triad or something similar) in that show didn't know where Earth was, its self-appointed mission to wipe out civilizations above a certain tech-level made it a definite threat and consequently a reccurring plotline was sabotaging the Triad or keeping Earth's coordinates from falling into its hands.

As I recall the mechs piloted by the three teens were orginally only armed with lasers for mining or collecting rock samples but later on were equipped with more powerful alien weaponry. They also picked up an alien woman whose homeworld was lost to the Triad, and an animal with a silly-sounding name that was supposed to serve as comic relief.

Comment: You are right, thank you kindly for helping me find it.

Comment: @user56296: Please click on the green check mark to accept the answer.