# Live action mecha shown on ytv

Tags: story-identification, space, mecha

This one is for you 90s kids. On YTV (Youth Television station in Canada ) In the early to mid-90s there was a Live action Sci-fi show, mived with CG space shots and mecha. It was about teens whom were lost in space and had to survive in a diffrent galactic area where humans were not existing, or were a extreme minority. It featured bipedal digigrade mecha that the three heroes piloted, and they were trapped/living on a ship that had disappeared. Wondering if anyone else might recall this show?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2805/late-80s-mid-90s-disney-tv-movie-with-mechs

Answer (score 2):

Eighties kid here, but I'll try to answer your question anyway.

As it would've aired a bit after my time I'm not sure if it was ever actually on YTV, but [Hypernauts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypernauts) appears to fit the bill otherwise. From Wikipedia:

> The premise of the series was that three cadets from the Academy of Galactic Exploration become lost in a Hyper Bubble (hyperspace) mid-jump and must band together with an alien named Kulai in order to survive in an unfamiliar part of the galaxy. Kulai (unbeknownst to the cadets) is a Chalim priestess from a planet called Pyria, a planet that was strip-mined by a warlike race called the Triiad, led by the Pyran traitor, Paiyin. The sole purpose of the Triiad is to wipe out intelligent races, and in the process acquire raw materials from their destroyed planets to continually create new war machines using automated self-replicating factory ships called "Makers."
>
> The Hypernauts, as they name themselves, cannot match the Triiad's firepower with their own so they must rely on stealth, wits and (occasionally) their modified 'mech suits' in order to escape the Triiad. They are based in an ancient abandoned exploration ship called the Star Ranger which is hidden in an asteroid field, the Star Ranger's obsolete AI is named Horten. For long range missions they use a four person shuttle called the Flapjack which like the Star Ranger is Hyper Bubble capable but has a much shorter range.