# Show from the '90s or '80s involving three teens fighting in green, yellow, or red mech suits

Tags: story-identification, tv

I need help identifying a show that involves three teenagers or young adults. They fought in mech suits. They were green, yellow, and red. I think they might have had a robot dog and it was live action people but '90s looking 3D CGI.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SciFi.SE! This question could be improved by looking at [this checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335) and [edit]ing any extra information you remember.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the check mark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

*[Hypernauts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypernauts)*, as per [Late 80s - mid 90s Disney TV movie with mechs](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2805/late-80s-mid-90s-disney-tv-movie-with-mechs)?

> The premise of the series was that three cadets from the Academy of Galactic Exploration become lost in a Hyper Bubble (hyperspace) mid-jump and must band together with an alien named Kulai in order to survive in an unfamiliar part of the galaxy. Kulai (unbeknownst to the cadets) is a Chalim priestess from a planet called Pyria, a planet that was strip-mined by a warlike race called the Triiad, led by the Pyran traitor, Paiyin. The sole purpose of the Triiad is to wipe out intelligent races, and in the process acquire raw materials from their destroyed planets to continually create new war machines using automated self-replicating factory ships called "Makers."

It's three teenagers, in colored suits/mechs, with a mix of live action and early CG.

[image: Color-coded mechs] [image: Color-coded suits]

No robot dog, but they do have a pet alien, Gloose, and there's a ship AI, Horten. I could see how the two could get mixed together.

[image: Image of Gloose, the pet alien]

### Hypernauts Opening